# How do I replace (select current_timestamp) with a filename that houses this same select statement?

Tags: postgresql, unix, psql, postgresql-copy

I am using PSQL. My command line is:

```
$\copy (select current_timestamp) to '/home/myname/outputfile.txt'
```

I would like to know, How do I replace "(select current_Timestamp)" with a filename that houses that same select statement?

ex:

```
$\copy (My_SQL_FILE.sql) to '/home/myname/outputfile.txt'
```

I've tried googling but I can't seem to find the answer.

```
$\copy (my_Sql_file.sql) to '/home/myname/outputfile.txt'
```

does not work

Answer (score 0):

You want to run a query stored in a file in a `\copy` statement, i.e. execute that query and store the output in a file? That is doable.

I've come across this use-case myself and wrote [`psql2csv`](https://github.com/fphilipe/psql2csv). It takes the same arguments as `psql` and additionally takes a query as parameter (or through STDIN) and prints the output to STDOUT.

Thus, you could use it as follows:

```
$ psql2csv [CONNECTION_OPTIONS] < My_SQL_FILE.sql > /home/myname/outputfile.txt
```

What `psql2csv` will basically do is transform your query to

```
COPY ($YOUR_QUERY) TO STDOUT WITH (FORMAT csv, ENCODING 'UTF8', HEADER true)
```

and execute that through `psql`. Note that you can customize a bunch of things, such as headers, separator, etc.